# alertdialogbox not closing even when work is done

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am making an app which shows lat long values I got all the code but I need a onPost resume method in which it checks for GPS enabled if it is enabled then it should do it work if not the it should remain on the same activity until unless it enables the GPS on its working now but its showing alertdialogbox  even when gps is enabled how to code if gps is enabled it should not show alertdialogbox please help me out if any one can.
   I Got a method but now its showing dialog box even after its enabled on

```
code on on resume is : 



    help me out if i am missing something
@override    
     AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
                alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Enable Gps to Continue");
                alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("If You Want To Enable Gps Go To Settings");
                alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
                alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Gps..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


                alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading Failed,Enable Gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }




Alertdialogbox not Disappearing even when gps is enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setting class to on resume

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = isLocationEnabled(context);

        Log.i("OnRe"," gps_enabled: "+ gps_enabled);

        if (!gps_enabled) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
            alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Enable Gps to Continue");
            alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("If You Want To Enable Gps Go To Settings");
            alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Gps..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


            alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading Failed,Enable Gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }


Created a different class
public static Boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
// This is new method provided in API 28
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            return lm.isLocationEnabled();
        } else {
// This is Deprecated in API 28
            int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
                    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
            return  (mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Main problem was it was give false evertime even i enable gps_enabled

Got this solution but want to know why that also did not worked?

if any one can help me out

Comment: hey thank you for your solution can uh please help my friend out with his problem " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913282/custom-recyclerview-using-adapter "

Comment: it would be a great help for both of us thank you in advance